# Image not showing up on canvas onload

Tags: javascript, image, onload

I'm trying to make a player image move around on a canvas. The player image doesn't show up on load. I used an alert to check the onload and it does seem to be running but the image is not displayed.

The player image does not show up if I only move left and right, and it does not show up if I only move up and down. The image does show up after I have moved in both the X and Y directions which makes me think that the X and Y are not correctly set until my animation function sets them. I can't see what is wrong with the initial X and Y onload though I'm using my own images on my computer but I just plugged in some random pictures so you guys could see something load.

I just put the whole code on here I don't know if that is too much but I'm not sure what I did wrong. I'm very new at this and this is my first time posting a question on here. I would appreciate if someone tells me what I'm doing wrong.

edit: I changed

```
var destX = xToCenter;
var destY = yToCenter;
```

to just the actual numbers

```
var destX = 260;
var destY = 220;
```

and that works but I don't really understand why. Can someone explain why I can't use xToCenter and yToCenter for onload but it works during the movement function?

[here is my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmjutsq1/7/)

```js
//create canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 600;

//create background canvas
var worldCanvas = document.getElementById("worldCanvas");
var wctx = worldCanvas.getContext('2d');
worldCanvas.width = 600;
worldCanvas.height = 600;

//player image
var avatar = new Image();
var sourceX = 32;
var sourceY = 32;
var sourceWidth = 16;
var sourceHeight = 32;
var destWidth = sourceWidth * 5;
var destHeight = sourceHeight * 5;
var destX = xToCenter;
var destY = yToCenter;
var speed = 4;
var faceRight = 0;
var faceLeft = 1;
var faceDown = 2;
var faceUp = 3;
var animation = [0, 32, 64];
var i = 0;

//background image
var worldMap = new Image();
var sMapX = 0;
var sMapY = 0;
var sMapWidth = canvas.width;
var sMapHeight = canvas.height;
var dMapX = 0;
var dMapY = 0;
var dMapWidth = canvas.width;
var dMapHeight = canvas.height;

var worldWidth = 1280;
var worldHeight = 873;

//center player
var xToCenter = (0.5 * dMapWidth - 0.5 * destWidth);
var yToCenter = (0.5 * dMapHeight - 0.5 * destHeight);

//load and draw background
worldMap.src = "http://img06.deviantart.net/75db/i/2013/332/5/2/random_background_by_electriczerox-d6vyp1u.png";
worldMap.onload = function() {
  wctx.drawImage(worldMap, sMapX, sMapY, sMapWidth, sMapHeight, dMapX, dMapY, dMapWidth, dMapHeight);
  alert("worldMap loaded");
}

//load and draw avatar
avatar.src = "http://www.somerandomfacts.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/jpg1";
avatar.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(avatar, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
  alert("avatar loaded");
}

//clear and redraw 
;
(function() {
  function main() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
    wctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    wctx.drawImage(worldMap, sMapX, sMapY, sMapWidth, sMapHeight, dMapX, dMapY, dMapWidth, dMapHeight);
    ctx.drawImage(avatar, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
  }
  main();
})();

//move avatar
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  var keyPressed = event.keyCode;
  switch (keyPressed) {
    //a moves left
    case 65:
      if (sMapX > 0) sMapX -= speed;
      destX = xToCenter;
      sourceX = faceLeft * sourceWidth;
      animationLoop();
      sourceY = animation[i];
      break;
      //w moves up
    case 87:
      if (sMapY > 0) sMapY -= speed;
      destY = yToCenter;
      sourceX = faceUp * sourceWidth;
      animationLoop();
      sourceY = animation[i];
      break;
      //d moves right
    case 68:
      if (sMapX < worldWidth - dMapWidth) sMapX += speed;
      destX = xToCenter;
      sourceX = faceRight * sourceWidth;
      animationLoop();
      sourceY = animation[i];
      break;
      //s moves down
    case 83:
      if (sMapY < worldHeight - dMapHeight) sMapY += speed;
      destY = yToCenter;
      sourceX = faceDown * sourceWidth;
      animationLoop();
      sourceY = animation[i];
      break;
  }
});

//animate while moving
function animationLoop() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(changeI);
}

function changeI() {
  if (i <= animation.length) i += 1;
  animation[i];
  if (i == animation.length) i = 0;

}
```

```css
.canvas {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.worldCanvas {
  border: 1px solid;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas" id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas class="worldCanvas" id="worldCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still learning but I think I can answer my own question. When I create a variable I should give it an initial value before I set it equal to another variable.